# What is the use and differences of Bitnami (PaaS) vs AWS EC2 (IaaS)?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, bitnami, paas

So I just deployed a Wordpress Application on AWS EC2, however I was wondering what the difference between an IaaS vs PaaS? I am required to deploy a website using a SaaS, IaaS, and a PaaS. If I have deployed EC2 & S3 the IaaS, what would be the point or would it even make sense to deploy Wordpress' Bitnami Cloud Application hosting? What are the benefits of using all three? Very confused kind of looking for an ELI5...thanks!

Comment: Why are you required to deploy a website using a SaaS, IaaS, and a PaaS? Is this an assignment, or an actual system requirement?

Comment: An assignment, that's why I was confused because I don't see the benefit of using a PaaS if we have it deployed on an SaaS lol. Nevermind though I'll delete.